# Changing NgModel properties in directive override all scope angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I would create one directive that get a property of my model and change this value, but when, in my directive, I assign the value, it overwrites entire object **retrieved by async Call**:
I have my **model Object**

```
object: {
  phone:"123456",
  name: "Jhon",
  surname: "Smith"
}
```

And I would change phone number, and I have
**my-html**

```
<input type="text" id="phone" class="form-control" data-ng-model="object.phone" custom-number>
```

and my directive:

```
.directive('customNumber', [ '$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            bindedModel: "=ngModel"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.bindedModel= "0000";

        }
}
```

And my model **object** it overwrite with only property phone, so now my model is:

```
object: {
 phone: "0000"
}
```

Why it overwrite my entire object and how can I avoid this?

**EDIT**

If I change my **html** in

```
<custom-number model="object.phone" />
```

And my directive:

```
var tpl = ' <input type="text" id="id" class="form-control" ng-model="model">';
    var init = 0;
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            id:'='
        },
        template: tpl,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('model', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                if (oldValue != newValue && init == 0){
                    scope.model = "0000"
                }
            });
        }
};
```

It change only right value, but I would do it only first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've tried your code in plunker but the directive modify only the value of phone.

I've also tried to create another directive that modify the name of the object and works correctly

check the code here:

```js
// Code goes here

angular.module("app", [])
.directive('customNumber', [ '$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            bindedModel: "=ngModel"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.bindedModel = "1000";

        }
}}])
.directive('customString', [ '$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            bindedModel: "=ngModel"
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.bindedModel = "Theo";

        }
}}])
.controller("myController", ["$scope",
function($scope){
  $scope.object = {
  phone:"123456",
  name: "Jhon",
  surname: "Smith"
};

}])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" >

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.8" data-semver="1.5.8" src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myController">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    
    <input type="text" id="phone" class="form-control" data-ng-model="object.phone" custom-number>
    <div ng-bind="object.name" ng-model="object.name" custom-string></div>
    <div ng-bind="object.surname"></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

**EDIT**

If you want change the value only the first time you can do a little change in your directive code:

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        model: '=',
        id:'='
    },
    template: '<input type="text" id="id" class="form-control" ng-model="model">',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var check = 0;
        scope.$watch('model', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            if (oldValue != newValue && check == 0){
                scope.model = "0000"
                check++;
            }
        });
    }}
```

Comment: Hello thankyou..The problem maybe that object value is async because input is inside ng-repeat?